# Loop through a multidimensional array?

Tags: c++, arrays

How would I loop through a multidimensional array? Say we had something like this:

```
class blah
{
    public:
    blah();
    bool foo;
};

blah::blah()
{
    foo = true;
}

blah testArray[1][2];
testArray[1][0].foo = false;
```

How would I go about looping through `testArray` to find which one of `foo` is false?

Comment: Same way you loop through any other array, except the body of the loop will be another loop

Comment: `testArray[1][0]` is out of range for your declared array

Comment: It's pseudocode. Doesn't matter. You can even fly in pseudocode.

Comment: @Lemmons: I was only pointing it out because if you were testing with that and couldn't find the false value, that may have been your problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
class blah
{
    public:
    blah();
    bool foo;
};

blah::blah()
{
    foo = true;
}

int testArrayFirstLength = 1;
int testArraySecondLength = 2;

blah testArray[testArrayFirstLength][testArraySecondLength];
testArray[1][0].foo = false;


for (int i = 0; i < testArrayFirstLength; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < testArraySecondLength; j++) {
        if (!testArray[i][j]) {
            blah thing = testArray[i][j]
        }
    }
}
```

That good? Or were you looking for something else?

Answer (score 8):

This one isn't dependent on magic numbers:

```
#include <cstddef>
for (size_t x = 0; x < sizeof(*testArray) / sizeof(**testArray); ++x)
for (size_t y = 0; y < sizeof(testArray)  / sizeof(*testArray);  ++y) {
  if (testArray[x][y].foo == false) {

  }
}
```

Having `x` in the outer loop leads to better caching.

Comment: +1...but maybe add `#include <cstddef>` and `using std::size_t`?  It's a pet peeve of mine.  What if (not likely, and not in the question) the rows are not all the same length?

Comment: @keith.layne I'll add the header, but the `std` isn't needed. Can array types even be defined with differing rows?

Comment: I feel dumb now, didn't know it was declared in the global namespace.  I'm checking on your question.

Comment: I guess not, but you could make an array of pointers that are arrays of different lengths, like so: `int* a[2]; a[0] = new int[7]; a[1] = new int[4];`.  I don't think my point really pertains to anything, I'm just your local devil's advocate. I think your technique would work anyway if you adjusted a little and then ordered the loops oppositely...you'd lose your optimization though.  I think that's another good question...won't most compilers reorder that loop anyway for the exact same reason?

Comment: Shouldn't the first loop use the stop condition of the second loop and vice versa?

Answer (score 0):

```
int x = 0;
int y = 0;

for( x = 0; x < 1; x++ ){
    for( y = 0; y < 2; y++ ){
       if( testArray[x][y].foo == false ){
           //yeah!
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (std::size_t i(0); i != 1; ++i){
    for (std::size_t j(0); j != 2; ++j) {
        if (!testArray[i][j].foo) {
            //testArray[i][j].foo is false
            //Perform the required operation
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested in c++ +14 (using pointers, so be safe)

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
int array[2][2][2]; 
int* pointer=&array[0][0][0]; 
for(int i=0; i<2*2*2; i++)
    {
        std::cout<<*pointer<<std::endl;     
        pointer++; 
    }
}
```

Comment: You didn't use the variable `i` here.